# After submitting form with laravel, show success in webpage

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

i need to show success message after submitting  form and inserting data to db with laravel.

the main idea is that after submitting the form, I insert data into db and after it I show message that insert was successful

form looks like this:

```
<div class = "draggable">
    <form class="popupForm"  method ="post" id = "popupForm" onsubmit="return insertAddonCategorie();">
        <table align="center" cellpadding = "10">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    Create new Category for Addons
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="newAddonCategoryName" name="category_name" maxlength="30"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Minimum</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="min_addons" id="newAddonCategoryMin" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Maximum</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="max_addons" id="newAddonCategoryMax" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Required</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="required" value="Required" id ="newAddonCategoryRequired"></td>
            </tr>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="isMandatory" value="" id="categoryMandatoryField"/>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" id = "buttonCreate">
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick = 'hidepopup()'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </form>
</div>
```

insertAddonCategorie() just checks if all the fields are filled and returns true.

in controller insert looks like this:

```
private function insertAction(Request $request){

$user = Auth::user();
$restaurant_owner_id = $user->restaurant_id;

$category_name = $request->input('category_name');
$max_addons = $request->input('max_addons');
$min_addons = $request->input('min_addons');
$isMandatory = $request->input('isMandatory');
$item_status = 1;

DB::table('addon_category')
            ->insert(['category_name'=>$category_name, 
                      'max_addons'=>$max_addons,
                        'min_addons'=>$min_addons,
                        'isMandatory'=>$isMandatory,
                        'addon_category_status'=>$item_status,
                        'restaurant_id'=>$restaurant_owner_id]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html  add this code for show message

```
`@if(isset($flag) && $flag === 1)
    <div class="alert alert-success">add record successful</div>
@endif`
```

in controller add this code

```
return view('yourviewname')->with('flag'=>1)
```